# Can a kafka streams client programatically determine its consumer lag

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a service that uses kafka streams api. I am wondering if there is way to determine how far behind is my service at consuming records. I want to able to query the consumer lag.

Here is some background about what I am trying to achieve. My service uses the streams api, it listens on an input topic, does some processing that involves state and outputs a record on an output topic.

I want to take care of the scenario where my service crashes and then comes back online a few hours later. During that time, there will be a huge backlog of records that have been accumulated on the input topic.

Once it comes back online, the service will start consuming all the accumulated records from the input topic and also output a lot of records on the output topic.

I want to be able to detect the fact that my service has a huge consumer lag and stall its output if that is the case.  That is, I want my service to consume all the accumulated input records until it has caught up with near real time and only then should it start outputting messages.

The best way I found so far is to hookup a `ConsumerInterceptor`.

`ConsumerInterceptor.onConsume()` method will be called each time records are read:

```
    ConsumerRecords<K,V> onConsume(ConsumerRecords<K,V> records)
```

From the `ConsumerRecords`, I can then get the timestamp of the records. If the timestamp is too far behind the current time then I would stall the output of messages.

Instead of basing myself on timestamps in the records, it would be better if I could somehow query for the consumer lag.

Maybe I cannot query for a consumer lag because it goes against the principle of what kafka is designed for. If someone has any suggestions or how I should approach my problem in general then please let me know.

As a side note, my service is not using the higher-level kafka streams DSL API, but it is using the lower level processor API.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `AdminClient#listConsumerGroupOffsets(...)` could be your friend.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thank you for your reply and I will look into the `AdminClient`.

I noticed that whenever I create my `KafkaStreams` with the following constructor: `KafkaStreams(Topology topology, java.util.Properties props)`

There is already an `AdminClient` that is being created within `KafkaStreams` because I can see in the logs the `AdminClientConfig` being printed in my logs.

Is there a way for me to reuse that already available `AdminClient` or do I need to create another instance of `AdminClient` ?

Comment: The `AdminClient` you see is internal to `KafkaStreams` and you cannot access it -- thus you will need to create your own instance.